# How to allow only alpha-numeric field value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server (T-SQL) we can do this like posted here:

http://www.sqlrelease.com/allow-only-alphanumeric-characters-in-a-column

How to do the same in PostgreSQL?

The following didn't worked -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy.checkalphanumeric(username character varying(32))
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
RETURN (SELECT CASE WHEN regexp_matches(username, '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%') > 
false THEN false ELSE true END);
END; $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION dummy.checkalphanumeric(username character varying(32))
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

And the ALTER query -

```
ALTER TABLE dummy.provisioning_user ADD CONSTRAINT 
CK_provisioning_user CHECK (dummycheckalphanumeric(username) = 1)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need for your own function.

Also: `%` is not a wildcard for a regular expression. The reason why that is used in the example is that the example is for SQL Server which doesn't support regular expressions (but I fail to see why a separate function would be necessary in SQL Server)

```
ALTER TABLE dummy.provisioning_user 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CK_provisioning_user 
   CHECK (username ~ '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$');
```

the constraint will check for values that only contain the characters (from a-z) and digits from 0-9. It will allow "nothing" though. If you don't want that you need to use `'[a-zA-Z0-9]+'` as the regex

Comment: Note: You are missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: This no longer works in Postgres 10+ because "set-returning functions are not allowed in check constraints"

Comment: @DustinKane: good point. `regexp_matches` wasn't a good idea to begin with.

Comment: Be careful with ranges in PG regex. They depend on collation, so e.g. they're normally case insensitive, and you might think `'[A-Z]'` only matches an uppercase character, but it matches lowercase all the same. From the docs: _"Ranges are very collating-sequence-dependent, so portable programs should avoid relying on them."_ https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

Comment: The $ and the ^ need to swap positions.